# snakemake samples validation schema for csv file

Tags: jsonschema, snakemake

I have a samples **csv** file with the following columns:

```
SMFID,Fastq1,Fastq2
```

I tried to use the following yaml to validate the schema in snakemake:

```
$schema: "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema"
description: an entry in the sample sheet
properties:
  SMFID:
    type: string
    description: sample name/identifier
  Fastq1:
    type: string
    description: path to fastq file (first mate)
  Fastq2:
    type: string
    description: path to fastq file (second mate)

required:
  - SMFID
  - Fastq1
  - Fastq2
```

But I get the following error:

> WorkflowError: Unsupported data type for validation.

Is there a way to specify that the input file is csv?

Comment: You could try using pandas-schema: https://pypi.org/project/pandas-schema/

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using snakemake's `snakemake.utils.validate` function after the csv has been loaded into a pandas DataFrame.

If the schema you provided is saved as `your_schema.yaml` and you have `samples.csv`:

```sh
SMFID,Fastq1,Fastq2
my_id,sread1,sread2
```

Then you can validate in your `Snakefile` like so:

```py
import pandas as pd
from snakemake.utils import validate

samples = pd.read_csv("samples.csv")
validate(samples, "your_schema.yaml")
```

This is further described [in the docs](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html?highlight=validate#validation).

Answer (score 1):

You would need to translate the file from CSV into JSON (or a JSON-compatible format that your evaluator supports).